# FieldContainer makes the form overflow

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJs 5.
I get a tree panel placed in the form.Because I want a label with the tree,so I put the tree into the field container then put the field container into the form.

```
......
{
  xtype:'form',
  items:[{
    xtype:'fieldcontainer',
    label:'tree',
    items:[{
        xtype:'treepanel',
        root:{
            expanded:false,
            children:[{...}]//This content is big enough to make the tree overflow.
        }
    }]
  ]
}
......
```

I know that the fix height config can solve it.But I don't want to give a fix height/maxHeight for the tree or for the container.I want it fulfil the whole space in the browser.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I have also tried the height config with a percentage value.But failed.

Comment: Have you tried to set the layout of your `fieldcontainer`?

Comment: No layout tried,which means it uses the container layout by default. Which layout will solve this issue?